# How to unlink a js file in yii2 specific targeted page?

Tags: php, yii2

How to unregister a js file in yii2 specific page in the view page.
Can i implement loading js in main layout, and only unlink in specific targeted page?

Comment: Use a different `AppAsset`, which you can define in your `controller action` or in `view` file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
unset($this->assetBundles['frontend\assets\YourAsset']);
```

It prevents loading of this asset in a view.